# Problems whose decidability status is unknown but known to be less hard than the halting problem

Tags: computability, reference-request, undecidability

Are there problems the decidability of which is unknown but it is known for certain that the problems are less hard than the halting problem.

Comment: see [A simple problem whose decidability is not known](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/18846/) on [cstheory.se].

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that by "less hard" you mean "reducible to", then any problem that is known to be in $RE$ but not known to be in $R$ satisfies this condition.

For example, take the PCP problem with 4 tiles, whose decidability is open. It is an easy exercise to reduce the problem (or any other problem in RE) to HALT.

Comment: It is not known that HALT can be reduced to PCP *with 4 tiles*. The latter is an open problem.

Comment: It is mentioned (I wrote that the decidability of it is not known, it is implied that there is no known reduction from HALT).